# Euclidean distance of all pandas rows to single row

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataset that gives the values of some songs, ie something that looks like:

```
    acousticness danceability energy instrumentalness key  liveness  loudness 
0        0.223      0.780      0.72       0.111        1     0.422    0.231
1        0.4        0.644      0.88       0.555        0.5   0.66     0.555
2        0.5        0.223      0.145      0.76         0     0.144    0.567
.
.
.
```

I want to find the songs/ rows that are numerically closest to another song, such as song `0`, using the *euclidean distance*.So I'd like to obtain something like:

```
    acousticness danceability energy instrumentalness key  liveness  loudness Euclidean to song 0
0        0.223      0.780      0.72       0.111        1     0.422    0.231       0
1        0.4        0.644      0.88       0.555        0.5   0.66     0.555      1.334
2        0.5        0.223      0.145      0.76         0     0.144    0.567     1.442
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual procedure for what you're trying to do, is to use one of sklearn's [pairwise metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics.pairwise), such as the [`cosine_similarity`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html), and build a similarity matrix with it:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity, euclidean_distances

cosine_similarity(df)
array([[1.        , 0.86597679, 0.38431913],
       [0.86597679, 1.        , 0.71838491],
       [0.38431913, 0.71838491, 1.        ]])
```

This gives you a square matrix with the indices representing the dataframe *song*  index.

---

**Similarity with a single item**

If you're only interested in the similarities with a specific song, say song `0`, you can specify a second a array as, so that the similarities are obtained using all items in the input matrix with a given item.

Since you mentioned the euclidean distance, here's one using sklearn's `euclidean_distances`. Note that we have tu subtract the result from `1`, since we have distances. If we want the actual distance, we can just keep the resulting array:

```
1-euclidean_distances(df, df.to_numpy()[0,None])
array([[ 1.        ],
       [-0.16977006],
       [-1.15823261]])
```

For the distance, just:

```
euclidean_distances(df, df.to_numpy()[0,None])
array([[0.        ],
       [1.43266989],
       [2.64328432]])
```

To update as a new column:

```
df['Similarity with song 0'] = 1-euclidean_distances(df, df.to_numpy()[0,None]).squeeze()
```

---

```
print(df)

   acousticness  danceability  energy  instrumentalness  key  liveness  \
0         0.223         0.780   0.720             0.111  1.0     0.422   
1         0.400         0.644   0.880             0.555  0.5     0.660   
2         0.500         0.223   0.145             0.760  0.0     0.144   

   loudness  Similarity with song 0  
0     0.231                1.000000  
1     0.555               -0.169770  
2     0.567               -1.158233
```

Comment: I'm trying to find the songs that are closest to song 0, so that I can rank them by closest sound

Comment: And why didn't you include that detail in the question? @aquamad96

Comment: Sorry I should've made it clearer. Is there a way to do such a thing or not?